# Laravel 7 React Scaffolding throwing Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler' when running "npm run dev"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to switch to react scaffolding from Bootstrap, but it's giving me errors about 'vue-template-compiler'. Below is my laravel, ui & nodejs version.

```
Laravel Version: 7,
Laravel UI: 2.4,
Node js: v16.15.1
```

These are the commands I've run:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^7.0 MyApp
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
php artisan ui react --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

Here's my package.json
[image: Package.json]

The Errors
[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon searching and reading a lot of articles I've finally found the answer, I've just installed it separately through npm.

```
npm install vue-template-compiler
```

This Fixed my problem.